# From list of directories, copy all subfolders to new location each with own folder per directory

Tags: vba, file, powershell, copy

I've searched around and can't seem to find a solution on my own so I'm asking for help!

I have a list of ~100 file locations/directories. They're located on the network and I need to grab them all and store them locally. I have some experience with VBA so I was going to try and use that (perhaps put the directories in a spread sheet and run a macro off that..)

When I store them locally I need to preserve the names of the directories they came from.

Any help would be MASSIVELY appreciated, automating this is becoming more and more necessary as I'm being sent more directories and a manual process will not scale well as this moves forward.

Any help at all, pointing me in a direction or offering advice is GREATLY appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Have you looked at the [copy-item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Copy-Item?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlet?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Copy-Item` cmdlet in PowerShell combined with the `-recurse` and `-container` switches to copy and preserve folder structure!  It's awesome for backing up a full network folder, and all sub-folders too!

Here is my Source directory.

```
C:\temp\stack>tree /F
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 0000000B 9215:D0CB
C:.
├───Dest
└───Source
    ├───1
    │       Archive.rar
    │       File01.bmp
    │
    ├───2
    │       Archive.rar
    │       File01.bmp
    │
    ├───3
    │       Archive.rar
    │       File01.bmp
    │
    └───4
            3.txt
            Archive.rar
            File01.bmp
            Ham.txt
```

As you can see, I have some files and folders in `Source` with subfolders and subfiles in each.  With this one simple PowerShell command though, I can move that whole structure easily into `Dest`.

```
copy-item -Path c:\temp\stack\source -Destination C:\temp\stack\Dest -Container -Recurse
```

Now I have that whole structure maintained in the `Dest` folder as well.

```
C:\temp\stack>tree /F
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 000000DE 9215:D0CB
C:.
├───Dest
│   ├───1
│   │       Archive.rar
│   │       File01.bmp
│   │
│   ├───2
│   │       Archive.rar
│   │       File01.bmp
│   │
│   ├───3
│   │       Archive.rar
│   │       File01.bmp
│   │
│   └───4
│           3.txt
│           Archive.rar
│           File01.bmp
│           Ham.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy-Item will work as mentioned. robocopy was also built for this exact purpose, and will run in cmd or Powershell.  Run `robocopy /?` for usage info.

You probably want something like:

```
robocopy "Y:\Network\Source\Location" "C:\Local\Machine\Destination\Location" /E
```

/E Means to copy the directory and all subdirectories.